# S is the smallest $\sigma$- algebra on $R$ containing $\{(r,s] : r\in Q\}$ where Q is the rational numbers. Prove that S is the Borel $\sigma$ algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

S is the smallest $\sigma$- algebra on $R$ containing $\{(r,s] : r\in Q\}$ where Q is the rational numbers. Prove that S is the Borel $\sigma$ algebra.

My Work-

I'm going to show that this contains an open sets. Then, this should be the smallest sigma algebra that contains open sets.
First let's show that the open interval contains in S.

Case 1-

suppose $a, b$ are both rationals. then $(a,b)=\cup(a, b-\frac{1}{n}]$. since each $(a, b-\frac{1}{n}]$ is in S, and S is an $\sigma$ algebra, $\cup(a, b-\frac{1}{n}]$ is in S. therefore $(a,b)$ contains in S. Hence, any Open set $O=\cup(a,b)$ is  in S.

Case 2-

suppose $a, b$ are irrationals. since rationals are dense in $R$ we can write $(a,b)=\cap(r_n, q_n)$ where $(a,b)\subset(r_n,q_n)$ and $r_n\rightarrow a$ and $q_n\rightarrow b$.
we proved earlier that $(r_n,q_n)\in S$. Therefore, $(a,b)\in S$.

Is this a good approach? I feel like there should more cases on this.

Comment: Indeed, because the rationals are dense in the real numbers, the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is generated by only considering intervals (open, half-open or closed does not matter) with rational bounds.

Comment: Okay. Thank you @S.Farr